# Express res.redirect causing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path, middleware

Using Node.js, Express, Socket.io, firebase admin+auth and Handlebars.

I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

When I used  `res.redirect('/login');` but it goes when I remove `res.redirect` have tried including the redirect type (301) changing the path to `../login` `/../login` but still has the error?

Really stumped on this one any help would be great!

Seems most other discussions about it stay it's a path issue?

Imports

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
```

Code that I think is relavent

```
// Express and Handlebars
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

Main issue code

```
// show login page before middleware check (works fine)

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login', {
        showTitle: true,
        title: 'Login'     
    });
});

// Auth Check All Pages HERE Catches access to all other pages
// Main Issue

app.use(function(req, res, next) {  
    console.log('[firebase.auth()] ', firebase.auth().currentUser);
    if(firebase.auth().currentUser === null){
        res.redirect('/login');
        return; // same problem without return
    }else{
       next();
    }

});

// all other routes...
```

is `express.static`causing it?

```
app.use(express.static('/public'));
const port = 3000;
http.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

login.handlebars

```
{{#if showTitle}}
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
{{/if}}


<form id="login" >
    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" value="ben@bnr.io"/>
    <label for="pass">Password</label>
    <input id="pass" type="password"/>
    <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is the error occurring?  Is it server-side or client-side?  Either way, please add the login template to your question as that's probably where the issue is.

Comment: At your initialization of handlebar, `hbs.engine` isn't defined. try using 
 `app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());` again it's advisable to use path for concatenating file paths.

Comment: @jfriend00 the code that's causing it is server-side but the error is showing client-side in the console also I never get replies this quickly and have just had a break after 3 hrs of this. Have added the template, I don't think it's that

Comment: Then, you have an error in your generated HTML that your browser Javascript interpreter is tripping up on.  Probably you have HTML mixed in with your Javascript.  We can't help you any further unless you show us the login template file and maybe also the generated HTML (from View/Source in the browser).

Comment: @jfriend00 have added that template

Comment: the error is caused res.redirect without it there is no error

Comment: Where's the rest of your HTML such as `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`?  You're not showing the HTML for a finished HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by the `res.redirect('/login');` redirecting scripts in the public folder, so the scripts src `js/client.js` would be redirected to `/login`.

It's because of the middleware `app.use(function(req, res, next)` fires on all HTTP requests.

**The Fixed** Changed it to using a function on the routes instead:

Example:

```
app.get('/', isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('home', {
        showTitle: true,
        title: 'Home'
    });
});
```

Function:

```
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {

    if (uid)
        return next();

    // IF A USER ISN'T LOGGED IN, THEN REDIRECT THEM
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
```